# How to skew in Unity with matrix values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to do some transform to elements in Unity for a project, with matrix values that I extract on a XML file :

```xml
<DOMBitmapInstance libraryItemName="Scene/Picture/CAM_U_cptgen_GEN_TOP_T1(4th_seat).png">
  <matrix>
    <Matrix a="0" b="1.66069030761719" c="-1.66069030761719" d="0" tx="178.5" ty="-673"/>
  </matrix>
</DOMBitmapInstance>
```

My question is, how can I skew my image, because 'a' and 'd' are supposed to be for x and y scale, and 'b' and 'c' are for y and x skew.
I need to display images and to animate them in Unity, so this values can change.
For now on, I extract all values and already apply 'a' and 'd'.
Thanks in advance !

In a previous version of the project, I worked on the same project but generated, not the source file (plans have changed like they say) and It was generated in js, and I could easily extract Skew value because It was a rotation value like '90' degrees. But for the same project, now I have this numbers I don't really know how to apply them into a Unity Transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution, I'll post here if someone needs one day to do the same as me.

```
public void SetSkew(float b, float c)
{
    float a = elementObject.transform.localScale.x;
    elementObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(c, a) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
}
```